# json in multiple pie chart using Highchart

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I have json data like this

```
var data=    {
        'A' : {
            'Total' : 123,
            'Cricket' : 76,
            'Football' : 12,
            'Hockey' : 1,
            'None' : 10

        },
    'B' : {
        'Total': 123,
        'Cricket': 76,
        'Football': 12,
        'Hockey': 1,
        'None': 10
    },
    'C' : {
        'Total': 123,
        'Cricket': 76,
        'Football': 12,
        'Hockey': 1,
        'None': 10
    }   
}
```

I want to populate this in HighChart..
I am using this approach [Highcharts - Multiple pie charts from json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33657746/highcharts-multiple-pie-charts-from-json)

but I need chart like this http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/pie-basic/

But I need three pie chart for A B C as in Above json.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this example: http://jsfiddle.net/kkulig/2jq0dvgL/

Use following code to prepare your data before passing it to the chart constructor:

```
var data = [];
$.each(item, function(prop, value) {
  data.push({
    name: prop,
    y: value
  });
});
```

Comment: You can use 'delete' operator just like here: http://jsfiddle.net/kkulig/9o4457pp/

Comment: One more question I want to set time that every 10 seconds only single chart should be displayed ..like first morning then afternoon then eveng

Comment: Thank you kamil but at the time loading ..first three get display then it display one by one using timer..

Comment: You are right - sorry for that. I've updated this fiddle and now everything seems to work fine.

Comment: Thanks a ton for your kind help :)